# Play 2.2 minify javascripts

Tags: minify, google-closure-compiler, playframework-2.2

How to tell Play to compile and create a minified version of my.js? After running 'play stage', I can't find it anywhere under **target/scala-2.10/resource_managed** or **target/scala-2.10/classes**.

```
app/
   assets/
      javascripts/
          main/
             some.js
```

EDIT 1: follow Raunak's comment, I tried this. But the minified js is still not created.

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
.settings(
        ebeanEnabled := true,
        requireJs += "mainProd.js", // files specified in requireJs will be optimized
        requireJsShim += "build.js", // build options for optimizer
        requireJsFolder := "js",
        routesImport += "se.radley.plugin.salat.Binders._",
        templatesImport ++= Seq("org.bson.types.ObjectId"),
        resolvers += "Mave2" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
        resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
        resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
        resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
        parallelExecution in Test := false,
        javascriptEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(base =>
              base / "app" / "assets" / "javascripts" / "main" ** "*.js"
           )            
)
```

EDIT 2: I found out all of js files in requireJsFolder would not be compiled at all if I gave javascriptEntryPoints.

Answer (score 0):

To run the minify process you can run the following command as per their [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.3/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler).

For example, to compile only .js file from the app/assets/javascripts/main directory:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
   javascriptEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(base =>
      base / "app" / "assets" / "javascripts" / "main" ** "*.js"
   )
)
```

To check the minify is generated normally during staging

you can use a `play dist` command to prepare standalone version of application similar to `play stage` command,  it will generate a zip file, instead writing the code into target directory. Then you can check the minified file exists or not

Comment: I tried this and added a some.js under app/assets/javascripts/main and your config. But it is still not working.